# use php date string in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

i have a date entry in yyyy-mm-dd format in mysql database. Using php i could get the date value

```
$row = $myresult['date'];
```

now i wish to alert this value in javascript

so i tried

```
var temp_date = <?php echo($row)?>;
alert (temp_date);
```

but that didn't work for me. The problem i feel i am facing is to maintain the string format of the datestring, which seems to be getting lost when used in javascript.
Any help?

Comment: As the fifth in a row to provide the very same answer allow me to withdraw mine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String literals are sorrounded by double or single quotes in JavaScript:

```
var temp_date = "<?php echo($row)?>";
alert (temp_date);
```

Comment: thanks, i was using VSPhp as the editor and it was reporting a syntax error when i typed the line, that made me wonder if my approach was right. It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Use [json_encode()](http://php.net/json_encode). This will turn PHP variables into valid javascript, so you don't have to worry about quoting/escaping etc.

```
var temp_date = <?php echo json_encode($row); ?>;
alert (temp_date);
```

Answer (score 1):

*This answer originally was a quasi exact copy of the other four first.*

If you need the *date information* as such, you could use Unix timestamps:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timefield) AS timestamp WHERE id = 1;
```

then just echo it in PHP into this JS snippet:

```
var mydate = new Date(<?php echo $row['timestamp']*1000; ?>);
```

You don't need quotes here, since you echo a number. This allows for, e.g.,

```
alert (mydate.getDate());
```

and the such.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You have to add quotes to your JavaScript variable assignation:

```
var temp_date = '<?php echo($row)?>';
alert (temp_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp_date = '<?php echo($row)?>';
alert (temp_date);
```

Add quotes. Otherwise it will error because strings without quotes are troublesome.

Answer (score -1):

.php

```
$smarty->assign("profile_date",date("Y/m/d"));
```

.tpl

```
var NowDate=new Date("{/literal}{$profile_date}{literal}");
```